# How to match list order

Tags: apex

Alert: not a developer here!

I have an ordered list of external Ids. Let's call it:

```
List<String> externalIds = new List<String>{'5', '1' ,'9', '3'};
```

I can use this list to get another list of the Accounts that correspond to those external Ids:

```
List<Account> myAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
                            WHERE External_Id__c IN :externalIds];
```

The important thing is that I need my list of accounts to reflect the same order as my original list of external ids. If the external Ids are 5,1,9,3 then I want the corresponding list of accounts to reflect/follow the same order.

I am not sure if there's an easy way to do this. Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Can you share what your overall objective is? It's possible there is a more idiomatic way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put the accounts in to a Map by External Id:

```
Map<String, Account> accountByExternalId = new Map<String, Account>();
for(Account record: [SELECT Name, External_Id__c FROM Account WHERE External_Id__c = :externalIds]) {
    accountByExternalId.put(record.External_Id__c, record);
}
```

In most cases, this is sufficient to map the records. It's not generally necessary to end up with a list of records in the External Id order. I don't think I've ever needed this sort of mapping in 15+ years of writing Apex, but, assuming you did actually need it, it's then simply a matter of:

```
Account[] orderedAccounts = new Account[0];
for(String externalId: externalIds) {
  orderedAccounts.add(accountByExternalId.get(externalId));
}
```

So, the entire algorithm would look like:

```
Map<String, Account> accountByExternalId = new Map<String, Account>();
for(Account record: [SELECT Name, External_Id__c FROM Account WHERE External_Id__c = :externalIds]) {
    accountByExternalId.put(record.External_Id__c, record);
}
Account[] orderedAccounts = new Account[0];
for(String externalId: externalIds) {
  orderedAccounts.add(accountByExternalId.get(externalId));
}
```

You could generalize this algorithm to make it reusable elsewhere:

```
public sObject[] getRecordsByOrder(sObject[] records, Object[] keys, sObjectField keyField) {
    sObject[] values = records.clone();
    values.clear();
    Map<Object, sObject> mappedValues = new Map<Object, sObject>();
    for(sObject record: records) {
        mappedValues.put(record.get(keyField), record);
    }
    for(Object key: keys) {
        values.add(mappedValues.get(key));
    }
    return values;
}
```

Which you can then use as:

```
Account[] orderedValues = (Account[])getRecordsByOrder(
  [SELECT External_Id__c, Name 
   FROM Account 
   WHERE External_Id__c = :externalIds],
  externalIds,
  Account.External_Id__c
);
```

Add error handling to avoid non-existent external ID values, etc if you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Map to get Accounts that correspond to those external Ids:

```
Map<string,Account> externalidwithAccMap = Map<string,Account>();

List<Account> myAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
                            WHERE External_Id__c IN :externalIds];

If(myAccounts.size() > 0){
    for(Account acc :myAccounts){
        externalidwithAccMap.put(acc.External_Id__c, acc);
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. It's not an "error" to iterate over an empty list. You don't need to do check if the list is empty first.